# Error: /dev/fd/63: line 1: Moved: command not found

Tags: bash, high-sierra

I am trying to install particle cli on macOS High Sierra.

When I run this command:

`bash <( curl -sl https://particle.io/install-cli )`

I get this error:

`/dev/fd/63: line 1: Moved: command not found`

Can anyone help me fixing this issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because the URL you have referenced - https://particle.io/install-cli - has moved.

The new URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spark/particle-cli-wrapper/master/installer/unix/install-cli

Comment: Adding the `-L` option to the `curl` command will make it work (it tells `curl` to follow redirects to the script's new location).

Comment: @GordonDavisson that could be the correct answer I would select .

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz I have reservations about blindly running a downloaded script without inspecting it first. Unfortunately this seems to be a common recommendation. It's one of those things that mostly works, but isn't particularly safe. Using `-L` makes it both 1) more likely to work, and 2) less safe. So I don't really feel I can recommend it enough to make it an "answer".